# Flask: Headless file upload

Tags: python-3.x, flask, file-upload

I want to create a small file upload web server with Flask.

The caviat is that i want this to be a headless server. No HTML files or templates server.

The user will hit the upload path with a (path+filename) to the file to be uploaded as a parameter.

The server, when the request is triggered will get that file and upload it. No forms.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly directly send a POST request to a server, without loading a form before.

You have to provide an endpoint on your server which accepts the POST request.

Your user could use e.g. [curl](https://curl.se/).